# I want to change the style of my app when a LinearLayout clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-styles

I want to give users the chance to change their favorite color..In other words, the purpose is changing (colorPrimary,colorPrimaryDark,colorAccent), I have added some LinearLayouts in Parameters fragment, but even adding "setTheme" in my code when LinearLayout clicked nothing happening .. please if there is a mistake in my code leave the solution in a comment .

[this how the PrametresFragment is looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F13rd.png)

My code :

ParametresFragment :

```
public class ParametresFragment extends Fragment {

    LinearLayout greenStyle;

    public ParametresFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parametres, container, false);



        greenStyle = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.greenStyle);
        greenStyle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getActivity().setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Green);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        return v;

    }

}
```

styles.xml  :

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Green" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#6ed75c</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#44ab32</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#fff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.nobar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: Do you see the Toast? Why are you implementing this as a click on a LinearLayout rather than with a Button some other more appropriate View?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice because the LinearLayout contains 3 View objects

Comment: So are you saying that you want to allow the user to click on an entire section of the screen that has child views rather than on just a button?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes .. and it work fine when I click on it, because the Toast shows up.. 
I have added the photo of my Fragment how is looks like

Comment: I assume that you want this theme change to be permanent for the next time that you start the app, right? Can you implement saving the theme setting in a SharedPreference? After you do so, see what happens when you leave the app and restart it. I know this doesn't address the issue of the immediate theme change, but it will help you see if you can actually change the theme permanently.

Comment: can you leave a comment how to do that, I mean the code!

Comment: This is not a code writing service. I gave you the keywords in my previous comment so that you can do some research and learn how to do it. The official Android documentation has very good tutorials for using SharePreferences.